# How to properly link libnfc on Windows 8?

Tags: linker, nfc, dllimport

I've successfully compiled libnfc and the examples are all working. Now I'm trying to compile one of those examples myself to find out how to do it.

The file I want to compile is in a different folder than libnfc self. When I compile it gives me the following errors (and warning):

```
C:\thesis\libnfc\dev>gcc -m32 test.c -o test -L"C:\thesis\libnfc\libnfc-build\libnfc" -lnfc
In file included from test.c:48:0:
utils/nfc-utils.h:97:14: warning: 'str_nfc_baud_rate' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2LqPG1.o:test.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `print_hex_bits'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2LqPG1.o:test.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `print_hex_bits'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2LqPG1.o:test.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `print_hex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2LqPG1.o:test.c:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `print_hex'
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2LqPG1.o:test.c:(.text+0xa87): undefined reference to `print_hex'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These functions are defined in nfc-utils. I assume these have also been compiled into the dll? I've put the folder utils with the contents nfc-utils.c and .h in the same folder but this won't help either.

The test.c file has the same content as the nfc-anticol.c file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it myself.

I clearly forgot to compile the utils/nfc-utils.c together with the test.c in the gcc -c step.
Did it in two steps and found it.

```
C:\thesis\libnfc\dev>gcc -m32 test.c utils/nfc-utils.c -c
In file included from test.c:48:0:
utils/nfc-utils.h:97:14: warning: 'str_nfc_baud_rate' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
In file included from utils/nfc-utils.c:37:0:
utils/nfc-utils.h:97:14: warning: 'str_nfc_baud_rate' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]

C:\thesis\libnfc\dev>gcc -m32 test.o nfc-utils.o -o test -L"C:\thesis\libnfc\libnfc-build\libnfc" -lnfc
```

This gave two warnings, but when I run it, it works.